# imported mesh visible in inspector but not in scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm not very experienced with unity, maybe this is really simple.

im trying to import the following mesh;
https://www.wien.gv.at/ma41datenviewer/downloads/geodaten/lod1_dxf/108083_lod1.zip

it's a triangle mesh of some buildings.

more meta data here:
https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/214a3e63-31aa-47de-a49c-5ea5a80330ed

when i pull it into unity (2021.3), in the inspector i see a preview of the mesh:
[image]

but when i pull the mesh into the scene, i don't see anything :(
[image]

i guess it has something to do with the import settings, but playing around with that didn't help.
[image]

thats how one of the sub-meshes looks when inspected:
[image]

how can i import this mesh, so that it is visible in the scene ?

Comment: have you extracted and assignet the materials? maby this is the fault.

Comment: @RonnyBigler i have played a round with the included material0 from the dxf and unitys standard materials, but to no avail